# MediaWiki <code> tag formatting

Tags: mediawiki

Where can I format `<code>` tag? Using default settings, letters are quite too small, and it doesn't look nice.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question? Also, some questions: what version are you using? Which skins have this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can format the `<code>` tag using MediaWiki:Common.css, especially increasing its font size. Edit that page like you normally edit a wiki page and add the special CSS rules for the `<code>` tag, but you will need the administrator rights to do it though.